# Git - Duplicate repo with history into existing repo

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have an existing repo with some basic files, like README.md.

I want to make a copy of another repo and merge it with the existing repo, while preserving the history.

The instructions for duplicating repos that I've found don't work (i.e. git clone --bare, git push --mirror [link](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/duplicating-a-repository)) since they would overwrite the old repo.

What I'd like is to duplicate the old repo, and then have a commit that addresses any conflicts before pushing it to the remote. Is this possible?

Comment: fetch and merge. You can fetch any ref you want, from any repo in reach, and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Is this, perhaps, an older version of the same repo?

Answer (score 0):

Add the other repo as a remote, and fetch it.

```
git remote add other <url or path to the other repo>
git fetch other
```

Now you have the other repo available as the remote `other`. You can reference its branches by prefixing `other/`. Their master branch is `other/master`. They have no common ancestor commit, so when merging use `--allow-unrelated-histories`.

Comment: Hmm, when I try to merge them I get the error "fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.". On github UI it shows "There isn’t anything to compare.
main and other are entirely different commit histories."

Comment: @user91240192094 Did you use `--allow-unrelated-histories`?

Comment: Yes. Without specifying `--allow-unrelated-histories` the error is fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories.

Comment: Seems like doing rebase instead of merging works.
1. git checkout -b <other-repo>
2. git remote add <repo-name> <repo>
3. git remote update
4. git rebase <remote>/<branch>
fix conflicts

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: @user91240192094 Rebasing is the right choice if the code was copied to a new repository and now you want to stitch the old and new repos back together. And yes, if you want to merge unrelated histories you must use `--allow-unrelated-histories`. Glad you got it working.